# Create overlapping and non-overlapping sliding windows in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sliding-window

I am trying to create overlapping and non-overlapping blocks of data from an array `Data` containing`N` elements. How can I correctly form sub-arrays of `Data` for any `N` and any `blksze`? The following code is for non-overlapping blocks throws error because of the number of elements exceed when creating sub-blocks. For example, let `Data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, then

- for overlapping case I should get : block size `blksze = 2`, I would get `block1 = [1,2], block2 = [2,3], block3 = [3,4], block4 = [4,5], block5 = [5,6]`
- for non-overlapping :  block size `blksze = 2`, I would get `block1 = [1,2], block2 = [3,4], block3 = [5,6]`

## Code snippet

```
N= 100;
n = 4;
Data = randi([1 n],1,N);
blksze = 10;
Nblocks = N / blksze;
counter = 1;
for i = 1 : Nblocks
    block{i} = Data(counter : counter + blksze - 1);
    counter = blksze + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract out overlapping blocks, I recommend using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create the indices and subset the matrix whereas non-overlapping blocks you can simply use [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

## Overlapping

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (1 : blksze), (0 : numel(Data) - blksze).');
```

The advantage of this method is that it uses broadcasting to generate the right indices per block.  This would thus be a 2D matrix where each row are the indices required to grab the data for the right block and the number of columns is dictated by the block size.

## Non-overlapping

```
ind = reshape(1 : numel(Data), [], numel(Data) / blksze).';
```

This simply reshapes the vector so that each row would be a unique set of indices that increases by 1 and the number of columns is dictated by the block size.

---

Finally, just index into `Data` to get what you need:

```
blocks = Data(ind);
```

Here's a running example using 6 elements:

```
>> rng(123); Data = rand(1, 6)

Data =

    0.6965    0.2861    0.2269    0.5513    0.7195    0.4231
```

With a block size of 2, or `blksze = 2`, here's what we get for both overlapping and non-overlapping:

```
>> blksze = 2;
>> indno = reshape(1 : numel(Data), [], numel(Data) / blksze).';
>> indo = bsxfun(@plus, (1 : blksze), (0 : numel(Data) - blksze).');
>> blockno = Data(indno)

blockno =

    0.6965    0.2861
    0.2269    0.5513
    0.7195    0.4231

>> blocko = Data(indo)

blocko =

    0.6965    0.2861
    0.2861    0.2269
    0.2269    0.5513
    0.5513    0.7195
    0.7195    0.4231
```

## Caveat

This code does no error checking in that we assume that there are enough blocks to capture all of your data.  If you have the number of elements in `Data` to be incompatible with the block size to capture all of the data in blocks of all the same size, an error will occur upon indexing.